# Finding Volume Label of a usb mass storage device using python

Tags: python, linux, usb

Could someone please tell me how I could obtain a usb mass storage device's volume label(the name displayed in the explorer, not the device name::/dev/sdX) using python?
 HAL has deprecated so please don't suggest it as an option.

EDIT: Is there a way to do it using pyudev or pyusb??

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use HAL you could do it by calling a [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

```
import subprocess

mounts = {}

for line in subprocess.check_output(['mount', '-l']).split('\n'):
    parts = line.split(' ')
    if len(parts) > 2:
        mounts[parts[2]] = parts[0]

print mounts
```